# Saving a scratch layer into an existing Spatialite database in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatialite

It is possible to save a QGIS scratch layer (QGIS 2.18) into all the usual formats - including as a new Spatialite database file.

Is there a way to save such a layer into an **existing** Spatialite database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the QspatiaLite plugin for QGIS you can create a temporary scratch layer in QGIS and then connect to your Spatialite DB in the plugin and select 'Import QGIS layer', select your scratch layer and it will be imported for you.